# Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass

Tags: java, grails, groovy, tomcat7, gvm

i am migratinga grails 1.3 application to grails 2.4.3 now when i run the grails app from command line i am getting the error :

Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter
for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass (NOTE: St
ack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter fo
r class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass

at runtime and the GrailsVm exsist with error

when i create the war for the app its getting created and viewing the grails jar in it i see the  DefaultGrailsServiceClass with the constructor in it .

```
public DefaultGrailsServiceClass(Class<?> clazz)
  {
    super(clazz, "Service");

    Object tmpTransactional = getPropertyOrStaticPropertyOrFieldValue("transactional", Boolean.class);
    this.transactional = ((tmpTransactional == null) || (tmpTransactional.equals(Boolean.TRUE)));
  }
```

i am running the app with java 8.031 and the internal tomcat dependency is 7.0.55 that is also compatible with java 8 . Any directions how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> i am migratinga grails 1.3 application to grails 2.4.3
>
> i am running the app with java 8.031

Java 8 is not supported with Grails 2.4.3.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.

Comment: i found that i was missing a jar that when i added the error was gone , i am able to compile and run the project with java 8 , what i found was every 2.X.X version was compatible with java 8 ,  so why am i able to compile and run the app

Comment: " what i found was every 2.X.X version was compatible with java 8" - Depending on what you mean by compatible, I would likely disagree with that.  There are things that will not work.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we added Java 8 support.

Comment: what jar is missing on which you've added it?

Comment: "what jar is missing on which you've added it?" - I don't know the answer to that, but one of the primary reasons we created 2.5 is we were moving on to Grails 3 (3.0 and 2.5 were released at the same time), 2.4.x and prior all have compatability issues with Java 8, and we wanted there to be a 2.x line that supported Java 8 for folks who needed to move to Java 8 but weren't ready to move to Grails 3.  2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we really supported Java 8.